# Sidekiq process on Elastic Beanstalk - Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - getcwd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sidekiq, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We're using [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) to send external API requests on Sidekiq workers that spin up [as a process](https://gist.github.com/hiattp/f2b8eca4a160c5f266e3) on our Elastic Beanstalk-managed EC2 instances.

Under the hood rest-client uses [netrc](https://github.com/heroku/netrc), and netrc [calls Dir.pwd](https://github.com/heroku/netrc/blob/master/lib/netrc.rb#L26) when `Dir.home` fails. We are seeing this error **sporadically**:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - getcwd
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/netrc-0.10.3/lib/netrc.rb:26 :in `pwd`
```

Which indicates that `ENV['HOME']` is not set, and apparently the current directory no longer exists. Generally `HOME` is set already on EB instances, and we've attempted to set it via `eb setenv` just to be sure.

The question is how this situation might arise on EB and how we can avoid it in the future. I hesitate to speculate but perhaps we are not killing Sidekiq processes correctly between deployments and old sidekiq processes survive, referencing old directories? I'm not terribly familiar with EB yet; any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As foreshadowed in both the question and some answers this was a rogue process that avoided termination, in this case due to a careless config change in one of our early deployments. Line 30 of our [sidekiq.config](https://gist.github.com/hiattp/f2b8eca4a160c5f266e3) controls the number of processes, and we dropped from 2 to 1 but did not manually remove the second process from the server after the change.

The moral of the story is that Sidekiq processes are not *only* vulnerable to unexpected behavior *during* deployments. Our errant process was happily completing jobs even without being stopped/started across multiple deployments, but anything that relied on `Dir.pwd` and presumably any other script requiring `ENV` data would fail *days* after a stable deployment if run on the persistent process.

If you see this type of failure, **be absolutely positive you don't have unexpected processes running from prior deployments**. This means ensuring they are properly terminated during deployment [as @JeffD23 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32514746/949328) but ALSO ensuring you don't have something hanging around from deployments of yore.

Comment: I've the same problem. I already suspected that this was the cause, but I could not get a final solution. Maybe I can solve this based on sidekiq.config you shared. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [sidekiq api](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API) might help you debug this.

First, get to rails console from beanstalk: `/var/app/current` run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c` then `require 'sidekiq/api'`

If you run `Sidekiq::Queue.new` it will return your enqueued jobs or `Sidekiq::RetrySet.new` for jobs scheduled to retry. If you have old jobs enqueued before your last deploy, that should confirm your suspicions about referencing a deleted directory.

> To safely shut down Sidekiq, you need to send it the USR1 signal as
>   early as possible in your deploy process and the TERM signal as late
>   as possible. USR1 tells Sidekiq to stop pulling new work and finish
>   all current work. TERM tells Sidekiq to exit within N seconds, where N
>   is set by the -t timeout option and defaults to 8. Using USR1+TERM in
>   your deploy process gives your jobs the maximum amount of time to
>   finish before exiting.

You might avoid this by setting up your sidekiq workers only try once, then die. Otherwise, your workers will keep failing for 25 retries or 21 days.

```
class NonRetryableWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false
  # your perform method
end
```

You can also set `sidekiq_options retry: 5` or any other integer to set the retry attempts explicitly.

If you're deploying with capistrano, you can manage jobs between deployments with the [capistrano-sidekiq](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq) gem

Comment: Interesting, so queuing or failing a job in one deployment means it will fail in the next deployment, like it remembers its context somehow? That seems undesirable if true, wonder if there is a workaround. Not showing any queued jobs atm via the sidekiq api but I'll definitely investigate further with that in mind

Comment: Actually we do have a few in the Sidekiq::RetrySet. Feels like this might be the issue

Comment: Sounds like that's it. I updated the answer with some additional info from the sidekiq deploy docs that explain the issue.

Comment: So unless I misunderstand the theory here the jobs either remember their failure context and you can't run jobs queued from one deployment in another (which is [not true](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2549)). Or Sidekiq is not shutting down correctly via the USR1/TERM sequence, but then we'd only see this failure during a deployment (which is not the case, I just saw one 10 minutes ago and we haven't deployed in days).

Comment: The job wouldn't remember the failure context, the problem seemed to be related to the deploy sequence running with with the old environment config. What kind of error message are you getting on the job itself, if you run Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.map { |x| x.item["error_message"] }

Comment: Solved it, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32566091/949328). I'm going to accept my answer but award you the bounty for the insights/references/effort; really helped. But some of your suggestions would be misleading to someone facing this issue in the future so I'd rather not highlight your answer in general: (1) having enqueued jobs does not confirm a deleted directory theory (2) retries are not related to this issue and should not be discouraged (3) switching deployment scripts (capistrano gems) sidesteps the issue. But those aside, thanks again!

Comment: Sounds good, this was an interesting issue. Glad you were able to get it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error exactly in the scenario described by you:

Some of our background workers failed to stop on deployments and then capistrano started deleting directories of old deploys. If a worker that was started in one of the old (now removed) directories is still around, then errors like the one you observed started occurring...

The solution is obviously to make sure that your old processes are properly terminated when deploying... Unfortunately I do not use neither *EB* nor *Sidekiq* so I can't help you out with specifics...

Comment: Well, good to know it isn't a novel problem :). Sounds like that supports my initial guess, now to track down why those processes aren't being terminated...

Answer (score 0):

I can't run your [sidekiq.conf](https://gist.github.com/hiattp/f2b8eca4a160c5f266e3) nor [0010_sidekiq.config](https://gist.github.com/kpheasey/d010608c2971408bf02c) (the closest to your config). I'm also not sure how you configured your sidekiq for the first time, maybe you can provide more detail about your `.ebextensions` and your config. When I tried to use your configuration, I got `which sidekiq` line is error:

**/var/log/eb-activity.log**

```
...

  ++ which bundle
  + BUNDLE=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/bundle
  ++ which sidekiq
  which: no sidekiq in (/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin)
  + SIDEKIQ= (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2015-09-08T15:24:52.326Z] INFO  [4963]  - [Application update/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/50_restart_sidekiq.sh] : Activity failed.
[2015-09-08T15:24:52.327Z] INFO  [4963]  - [Application update/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Activity failed.
[2015-09-08T15:24:52.327Z] INFO  [4963]  - [Application update/AppDeployStage1] : Activity failed.
[2015-09-08T15:24:52.327Z] INFO  [4963]  - [Application update] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy failed
```

But, I'm using another `.ebextensions`: https://github.com/jolks/ebextensions (Note: Don't forget to set `RAILS_ENV` to your EB environment variables). It's run properly. Basically, the `.ebextensions` try to restart sidekiq after your app has just been deployed.

Comment: Not sure where to go based on your response...our sidekiq config appears to work fine most of the time; kind of looks like you haven't run bundle or something since `which sidekiq` shouldn't fail if installed and we don't have that issue. Our `RAILS_ENV` is set correctly.

Comment: Could you give your `.ebextensions` related to the sidekiq?

Comment: That's what [this](https://gist.github.com/hiattp/f2b8eca4a160c5f266e3) is, you've already been referencing it. We don't have other config files related to sidekiq

Comment: When you run `bundle install` to install sidekiq?